# Extensions purchased on market place won't appear under extension manager

Tags: magento2, marketplace

Purchased few extensions on the marketplace. Followed the official Magento 2 documentation for the installation method via Web Setup Wizard from Admin Panel

1. Clicked Install on the purchase success page
2. The page redirected to the access keys page
3. Copied the public and private access keys
   On my Magento 2 CE admin page, clicked `System > Tools > Web Set Up Wizard Clicked Extension Manager`
4. Added my access keys from step 2
   expected to see '5 Extensions ready to install' - however, this page still displays 0. Any help is appreciated.

Also, there's no wide range of support available for this well known issue on Magento dev docs, etc. weird

[image]

Comment: Anyone could help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the workaround in this reference link:

[Extension Manager shows no extensions in Magento Commerce 2.3.x](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043980352-Extension-Manager-shows-no-extensions-in-Magento-Commerce-2-3-x)

Comment: thanks but I am not really looking into CLI or by command line and trying to get it working from Web setup wizard. I already visited that link but that's not really a workaround for beginners who want to use the easy way of installing extensions from extension manager.